# Using Intel Fortran compiler in VSCODE with makefile - `make: ifort: Command not found`

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, intel-fortran

I am new to Fortran, so please bear with me. I have a Fortran file that runs with the Intel `ifort` compiler. I can run the command `ifort -fpp -D IFORT discrete-kb-edits.F -lpgplot` from the command line, and it will compile the file to `a.out` and works.

Now, I am trying to setup VSCode 1.68 on Ubuntu 20.04LTS with Fortran support. So I configured the C/C++ plugin and the Fortran Breakpoints plugin. I also created a Makefile, as below, and I setup a `tasks.json` file, to run the make file from VSCode.

The problem is that when VSCode runs the `make`, it is not finding `ifort`. I am getting an output that looks like this:

```
> Executing task: make -j4 <

    ifort -fpp -D IFORT discrete-kb-edits.F -lpgplot
    make: ifort: Command not found
    make: *** [Makefile:7: main.o] Error 127
    The terminal process "/usr/bin/zsh '-c', 'make -j4'" failed to launch (exit code: 2).
```

Somehow I am able to compile from the terminal and find `ifort` from the regular terminal, but when compiling from VSCode tasks, I get an error about `ifort` not found.

The reference to the Intel compiler is in the `.zshrc` file. I run `source ~/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh` in that zsh config. So it seems like when running the Vscode task, it does not load the terminal config before running `make`.

Is there a way to configure VSCode to work with `ifort`?

Here is the make file and task configuration if it helps. Let me know if any additional information is needed.

```
Makefile:

# variables
FC=ifort
FFLAGS= -fpp -D IFORT

# compiling
main.o: discrete-kb-edits.F
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) discrete-kb-edits.F -lpgplot

# cleanup
clean:
    rm *.o a.out

# run
run:
    make
    ./a.out
```

VSCode tasks.json file.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "make",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make -j4",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @krishnab! Did you find a more elegant solution than my answer? I would be interested, if there was one.

Comment: @TilPiffl I have not had to work with Fortran for the past few months, but I actually just had to install intel oneapi Fortran on my second computer this past weekend. Seems like there are some changes in the oneapi installation process, so those changes might make a difference for the interface to VSCode. I will probably try this in the next few days.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by sourcing the `setvars.h` in the tasks.json:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "make",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "bash -c 'source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh --force && make'",
            "args": [],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The `--force` is only required if it could happen that the file was somehow already sourced before.